# Adjustable current limit control

Tags: current, current-source, current-limiting

How can I add an adjustable current limit control to the circuit below? Please explain with schematic.

The output value doesn't matter to me; it is important for me to learn how to change and control the current with this [UC3842AD8](https://www.ti.com/lit/gpn/UC3842A) IC.
The input current is 15 amps and the output is suitable for me from 400 mA to 15.

My experience showed that pin 3 of this IC has mostly 0 and 1 states and tampering with it makes the output of the circuit unstable.
Probably changing the amp should be through feedback or an external factor.

[image]

Comment: I think you want "adjustable current limit control". Is that correct?

Comment: Please explain what a "current control volume" is.

Comment: @Transistor
 Yes that's right
Thanks for your tips
I edited the question

Comment: I edited the question
But it is still closed
Why?

Comment: @MRezaHadi People have to vote to reopen it first; just wait for people to see that it has been edited. It might help to add additional information, though, like what the circuit is meant to do (looks like a flyback converter, but confirm if that's true or not) and what current you want to have an adjustable limit (input current? output current? switch current?).

Comment: @HearthThank you for your guidance
The input current is 15 amps and the output is suitable for me from 400 mA to 15.

Comment: "*The input current is ...*" That's better! Put all the information in your question. People might miss it in the comments and comments can be deleted.

Comment: It might be possible to use the ISENSE input to shut down at some level of overcurrent. The datasheet shows how to use an SCR to latch the shutdown. You could change R7 to different values using a switch, or add an amplifier with adjustable gain for continuously variable overcurrent trip. This is more an answer than comment. I'll vote to reopen.